# Filter api data in Angular 8 service?

Tags: angular, api, filter, service, webapi

I am in new in angular 8. I am currently working on angular 8 project.
Please Help..

## How to create a Service with ApI

=> Here is Example Request API:

```html
curl --location --request POST 'https://qa.wapd.com/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "query": "query($filter: OrderFilter, $sort:OrderSorter, $limit:Int!, $offset: Int) { orders(filter:$filter, sort: $sort,limit:$limit, offset:$offset) { total,data {id,createdAt,amount,dealer{company{name}},transactions{...on RegistrationInfo{createdAt,code},...on DepositionInfo{stripe{status,card{funding}}}}}}}",
 "variables": {
  "sort": {
   "createdAt": "DESC"
  },
  "filter": {
   "createdAt": {
    "gte": "2019-12-01T08:35:00.000Z",
    "lte": "2019-12-31T18:29:59.999Z"
   },
   "state": {
    "os": "COMPLETED"
   }
  },
  "limit": 10,
  "offset": 1
 }
}'
```

```html
#Services code#
_________________________________
createData(graphql):Observable<createData> {
  let body = JSON.stringify(graphql);
  return this.http.post<createData>('https://qa.ward.com/graphql', body, httpOptions);
}
```

**TS**

```js
 this.dataservice.createData(data).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res, 'res')
    })
```

## Response data from api

```js
{
  "data": {
    "orders": {
      "total": 17,
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 10896,
          "createdAt": "2019-12-30T07:18:19.182Z",
          "amount": 6000,
          "dealer": {
            "company": {
              "name": "Warpspeed "
            }
          },

        },
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to create a service for filter in angular 8

Comment: You've not given any Angular code or shown any evidence of your research into how you can make HTTP requests in Angular. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PushpendraTripathi, what is your response and what to filter in the response? please post it too.

Comment: @smart74 Please check it

Comment: @KurtHamilton please check in angular code.